# Run KeePassX on ubuntu phone

Tags: ubuntu-touch, keepassx

I ordered a BQ Ubuntu phone in the last flash sale. Once it arrives I'd like to run KeePassX on it. Does anyone with experience with the phone (perhaps on a Nexus 4) know whether KeePassX runs on it? If not, does anyone with KeePassX coding experience know whether it's something one could easily port?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no X11 support, hence you cant run any X11 software on it.